# How to get the Exif Metadata for the PDF document file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, exif

With flutter_exif and native_exif lib, i got image file details but it doesn't return details of file format PDF.

Comment: can you give me some reference to get pdf exif data. I have tried all the popular exif flutter library. but it doesn't give the result